# Python version displayed different than installed version [WINDOWS]

Tags: python, python-3.x, version

python version is displayed as `Python 2.7.14` when checked in cmd (strange because I have always installed python 3.6 onward). But python shell in IDLE shows `Python 3.7.6`. I was notified of this when using `f''` strings got errors.
Also python path in environment variables is set to `python37`. I was wondering why this was happening and how to change it.

P.S: I have not tried reinstalling python yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your environment variable is set to the correct Python executable path.
You can find your active executable with `where python` on windows and with `which python` on Linux. I guess you have an old executable active on your machine.

happy coding,
breadberry

Comment: thanks but environment variable is set to the `3.7` version itself. I guess I'll try reinstalling python.